# How do you create a templated custom matcher with gmock

Tags: c++, unit-testing, testing, googlemock

I wanted to use `WhenDynamicCastTo<T>(m)` from: https://google.github.io/googletest/reference/matchers.html#pointer-matchers

But the thing I want to dynamic cast is in a `shared_ptr` and `WhenDynamicCastTo` doesn't work with a smart pointer.

I tried to make my own version that works with smart pointers and I'm not sure how to make a templated matcher, I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
template <typename To>
MATCHER_P(WhenDynamicPointerCastTo<To>, matcher, "")
{
    // Use std::dynamic_pointer_cast here
}
```

Doing this does work but I'd like to hide it behind a single matcher:

```
template <typename To>
std::shared_ptr<const To> dynamic_smart_pointer_cast(
    const std::shared_ptr<const parent>& p)
{
    return std::dynamic_pointer_cast<const To>(p);
}

EXPECT_CALL(*mock_, func(
    ::testing::ResultOf(
        dynamic_smart_pointer_cast<child>,
        ::testing::Pointee(...))));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wanted to add an answer as I found a few ways to do it in the end.

I was able to actually use the gmock built in `WhenDynamicCastTo`.

The function I was mocking was like:

```
void func(const std::shared_ptr<interface_type>& i);
```

When I tried to use `WhenDynamicCastTo` like this it was complaining about the type I was casting to being abstract (It had a pure virtual function as well):

```
EXPECT_CALL(*mock_, func(
    ::testing::Pointee(::testing::WhenDynamicCastTo<impl>(<do_matching>))));
```

To make this work with gmocks built in `WhenDynamicCastTo` I had to change the template parameter to a reference:

```
EXPECT_CALL(*mock_, func(
    ::testing::Pointee(::testing::WhenDynamicCastTo<const impl&>(<do_matching>))));
```

I was able to make Erik Man's suggesting work with some changes to the template parameters and thought I'd add it incase someone wanted to do something like that:

```
template <typename To>
class WhenDynamicPointerCastToMatcher
{
public:
    explicit WhenDynamicPointerCastToMatcher(
        const ::testing::Matcher<std::shared_ptr<To> >& matcher) :
            matcher_(matcher)
    {
    }

    void DescribeTo(::std::ostream* os) const
    {
        GetCastTypeDescription(os);
        matcher_.DescribeTo(os);
    }

    void DescribeNegationTo(::std::ostream* os) const
    {
        GetCastTypeDescription(os);
        matcher_.DescribeNegationTo(os);
    }

    template <typename From>
    bool MatchAndExplain(From from, ::testing::MatchResultListener*) const
    {
        const std::shared_ptr<To> to{std::dynamic_pointer_cast<To>(from)};

        // To-Do: describe failures to the listener
        return matcher_.Matches(to);
    }

private:
    static void GetCastTypeDescription(::std::ostream* os)
    {
        *os << "when dynamic_pointer_cast";
    }

  const ::testing::Matcher<std::shared_ptr<To> > matcher_;
};

template <typename To>
inline ::testing::PolymorphicMatcher<WhenDynamicPointerCastToMatcher<To> > WhenDynamicPointerCastTo(
    const ::testing::Matcher<std::shared_ptr<To> >& inner_matcher)
{
    return ::testing::MakePolymorphicMatcher(
        WhenDynamicPointerCastToMatcher<To>(inner_matcher));
}

EXPECT_CALL(*mock_, func(
    WhenDynamicPointerCastTo<const impl>(::testing::Pointee(<do_matching>))));
```

Answer (score 0):

Following is based on how the `WhenDynamicCastTo` works in the gmock source code (untested), some result printing has been removed because it uses helpers from gmock's `internal` namespace.

```
template <typename To>
class WhenDynamicPointerCastToMatcher {
 public:
  explicit WhenDynamicPointerCastToMatcher(const Matcher<To>& matcher)
      : matcher_(matcher) {}

  void DescribeTo(::std::ostream* os) const {
    GetCastTypeDescription(os);
    matcher_.DescribeTo(os);
  }

  void DescribeNegationTo(::std::ostream* os) const {
    GetCastTypeDescription(os);
    matcher_.DescribeNegationTo(os);
  }

  template <typename From>
  bool MatchAndExplain(From from, MatchResultListener* listener) const {
    To to = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<To>(from);

    // TODO: describe failures to the listener
    return matcher_.Matches(to);
  }

 private:
  static void GetCastTypeDescription(::std::ostream* os) {
    *os << "when dynamic_pointer_cast, ";
  }

  const Matcher<To> matcher_;
};

template <typename To>
inline PolymorphicMatcher<WhenDynamicPointerCastToMatcher<To>>
WhenDynamicPointerCastTo(const Matcher<To>& inner_matcher) {
  return MakePolymorphicMatcher(
      WhenDynamicPointerCastToMatcher<To>(inner_matcher));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find a completely nice way to do it easily using the template parameter, but here are couple of workarounds that seem good enough to me. Assuming we have the following types:

```
struct A {
    virtual ~A() = default;
};
struct B: public A {
    B(int x) { this->x = x; }
    int x;
};

struct Foo {
    virtual void foo(A*) {}
    virtual void bar(std::shared_ptr<A>) {}
};

class MockFoo : public Foo {
public:
    MOCK_METHOD(void, foo, (A*), (override));
    MOCK_METHOD(void, bar, (std::shared_ptr<A>), (override));
};

bool operator==(const B& lhs, const B& rhs) { return lhs.x == rhs.x; }
```

1. Infer the casted-to type from the object you are matching against:

```
MATCHER_P(WhenDynamicPtrCastTo, val, "") {
    auto raw = arg.get();
    return Matches(WhenDynamicCastTo<decltype(val)*>(Pointee(val)))(raw);
}
```

use case:

```
TEST(xxx, yyy) {
    MockFoo mf;
    B b1{5};
    std::shared_ptr<A> ptrB1 = std::make_shared<B>(5);
    EXPECT_CALL(mf, bar(WhenDynamicPtrCastTo(b1)));
    mf.bar(ptrB1);
}
```

2. Additional dummy matcher argument to infer a possibly different type for a cast:

```
MATCHER_P2(WhenDynamicPtrCastTo, val, castTo, "") {
    auto raw = arg.get();
    return Matches(WhenDynamicCastTo<decltype(castTo)>(Pointee(val)))(raw);
}
```

use case:

```
// note that second arg doesn't necessarily need to be b1
EXPECT_CALL(mf, bar(WhenDynamicPtrCastTo(b1, &b1)));
```

3. Same as before, but write your matcher from scratch and possibly provide your own diagnostic messages:

```
MATCHER_P2(WhenDynamicPtrCastTo, val, castTo, "") {
    auto casted = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<std::remove_pointer_t<decltype(castTo)>>(arg);
    return casted && *casted == val;
}
```

Like before, it can be implemented with or without additional argument.